# String manipulation | Competitive Programming

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a String (lowercase letters) of size N with 1 based index.
Now I am given Q queries and each query consists of two integers x,y.
For every query I have to print min number of deletion from substring(x,y) (x,y included) such that substring has same frequency of distinct characters.

For example: consider a query which forms the substring abbccd,
now min no. of deletions in it are 2(1b,1c).

1<= N,Q <= 10^5

1<=X<=Y<=N

I tried the brute force approach where for every query I calculated frequency of characters and then calculated deletion by equating all frequencies to min frequency.

But I know that this approach is wrong and will also result in TLE. Can anyone help me with it.

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class q1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int q = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int x,y;
    while(q>0){
        x = in.nextInt();
        y = in.nextInt();
        String temp = s.substring(x-1, y);
        char c[] = temp.toCharArray();
        int count[] = new int[26];
        //calculating the frequencies.
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            count[c[i]-'a']++;
        }
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if(count[i]!=0 && count[i]<min){
                min = count[i];
            }
        }
        int deletions = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if(count[i]!=0){
                deletions += (count[i]-min);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(deletions);



        q--;
    }
}

}
```

[Problem Link](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNXrXiVbHEL4YnYIX0r4j5i7AePDyGb6zdHzN6Vh1AbgA_2qY2P9528JskdyA87BA?key=NVZhZXVYb1VqejFNWDU1MTYxSGxadHF5d3dqMVp3)

Comment: Mine is O(n) for every query and we have almost N queries. So its O(n2) in total. This approach lead to TLE.

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with Java.

Comment: I prefer that whosoever provides some solution to the problem, provides in java so that I can understand it completely. Hence the tag.

Comment: @weston I have added the code.

Comment: Ahh, so there is only one input string. And each query runs over just part of it. Now I can see how it can be better.

Comment: @weston exactly, we have one string and q queries over it.

Comment: Is this a code jam sample or something? I'd like to see the original puzzle if you can link to it? Or if not, where can I get sample data to try it?

Comment: It was asked in one on the competitions on hackerearth, the original puzzle link is restricted. Even though only one public test case(abbccd) was available which I have included in the problem statement . All other test cases were hidden from the participants.

Comment: @RishabhAgarwaljain Since you already know about the question, can you elaborate the problem by adding some examples?

Comment: @BandiKishore I hava also added the problem statement in form of a screenshot as link was not accessible

Comment: @weston N,Q lies in 1 to 10^5

Comment: @RishabhAgarwaljain Can you provide an example of a String, values of x,y and what is the output for that? I'm not able to grasp the question here.

Comment: @BandiKishore see the link to image in problem statement, it has a sample test case and output at the end.

Comment: @RishabhAgarwaljain My Bad, I didn't see the link after your edit. I could find a couple of improvements in your code like trying not to use `substring` and removing the min loop(by calculating it in freq. loop). But the code will not work for all scenarios. Consider input as `abcdabcd` and `1 7`, the output is suppose to be 1. In string `abcdabc` if you remove d (that is one character) the count of character becomes equal. As question says you get to `delete all of a character` as well. I'll see if I can come up with a logic for these.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132592/discussion-between-rishabh-agarwal-jain-and-bandi-kishore).

Comment: Is there any judge?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with O(26*26) steps per query.
Made a cumulative frequency array to store the frequency of every character up-til the "ith" position in the string.

`dp[i][0]` is the frequency of "a" in the string from the index 1 to i inclusive.
`dp[i][1]` is the frequency of "b" in the string from the index 1 to i inclusive.
and so on up-til 25 for "z".

Now in every query we can calculate the frequency of every character in the sub-string x to y, by subtracting frequency of a character "i" up-til "x-1" from the frequency of the same character up-til "y" i.e.

`freq[i] = dp[x-1][i] - dp[y][i];`

Now once we have the frequency of every character in the sub-string we can iterate over these frequencies and calculate the number of deletions for every unique character.

For example if we have a sub-string "ddddbbacc"
freq of "a" is 1
freq of "b" is 2
freq of "c" is 2
freq of "d" is 4

`frequencies = [1, 2, 2, 4]`
at first iteration we try to make all the frequencies equal to `freq[0]` i.e 1.
to do so we delete one char from the characters having `freq = 2` and 3 characters from the character having `freq = 4`.
this gives us a answer of `1+1+3 = 5`.

In second iteration we try to make all the frequencies equal to `freq[1]` i.e 2.
to do so we delete 3 characters from the character having `freq = 4`.
and we also delete all the characters whose `freq < 2` 
this gives us a answer of `1+2 = 3`.

In worst case it takes `26*26` steps per query.
Found the question
[here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/string-algorithm/basics-of-string-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/string-queries-1/)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class q1 {

static int[][] dp = new int[100005][27];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int q = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    String s = in.nextLine();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){                   //O(N*26)
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            dp[i+1][j] = dp[i][j];
        dp[i+1][(int)(s.charAt(i))-(int)('a')]++;
    }
    
    int x,y;
    while(q>0){                                             //O(Q*700)
        x = in.nextInt();
        y = in.nextInt();
        int freq[] = new int[27];
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)                         //O(1)
            freq[i] = dp[y][i] - dp[x-1][i];
        ArrayList<Integer> f = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)                         //O(1)
            if(freq[i] != 0)
                f.add(freq[i]);
        Collections.sort(f);                                //O(26*log26)
        int ans = s.length() + 1;
        int drop = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++){                  //O(26*26)
            int currans = drop;
            for(int j = i+1; j < f.size(); j++)
                currans += (f.get(j)-f.get(i));
            if (ans > currans)
                ans = currans;
            drop += f.get(i);
        }
        if (drop < ans)
            ans = drop;
        System.out.println(ans);
        q--;
    }
}

}
```